# add css class to jeditable input field

Tags: css, jeditable

How can i add a simple class tag to a jeditable input field? On the developer's website (http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable), under "How to style elements?", he says this can be done this way:

```
$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
    cssclass : 'someclass'
});
```

Unfortunately this will add the class to the `form` tag instead of the `input`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same question and did the following to style the 'input' element.

## JAVASCRIPT

```
$('.editable').editable('http://www.example.com/save.php', { 
    cssclass : 'someclass'
});
```

## CSS

```
.someclass input {
    width: 100%;
    ...
}
```